# Import append vba MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, append

Need help with the Access VBA
I am trying to import spreadsheets from excel into access. Once it is imported it will be appended into a different table and the import table will be deleted so that i can then import a new spreadsheet. However i have error when appending i need to append the entire table because i will not always know the header from the spreadsheet and how many their are. 
Please Help. Below is the code i have been work on.

Module-

```
Option Compare Database

Function selectFile()
Dim fd As FileDialog, fileName As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.AllowMultiSelect = False

If fd.Show = True Then
    If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
        fileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
Else
    'Exit code if no file is selected
    End
End If

'Return Selected FileName
selectFile = fileName

Set fd = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
Set fd = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Function
```

VBA -

```
Private Sub cmdImportNoDelete_Click()
'Unset warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Import spreadsheet
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Import", selectFile, True

'SQL append statement, Needs to append entire table (must be able to append multiply table with different headers
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Tbl_ImportDump * FROM Import"

'SQL delete Table
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Import"


DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the fundamental issue you're facing that `Tbl_ImportDump` and `Import` have different sets of fields ("headers") ... one table includes fields not present in the other, or maybe both have fields for the same data but the field names and/or data types don't match exactly?  If that is the problem, showing us the code you use to select an Excel file is not helpful.

Comment: HansUp
The sheets have for the most part similar field names but there are some that have new fields or different name fields. I want to dump all this into one table to then i can write some qry to identify fields and create a standard naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Tbl_ImportDump must exist. If it doesn't already, create it:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL _
    "CREATE TABLE Tbl_ImportDump (Col1 Col1DataType, Col2 Col2DataType, etc)"
```

Then after importing your spreadsheet (as table Import, as you've already done), get the column names in the Import table, and put these into the insert statement:

```
dim ImportCols as String: ImportCols = ""
dim ii as long
dim rs as Recordset

rs.OpenRecordset "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Import"
for ii = 0 to 2
    ImportCols = ImportCols & "," & rs.Fields(0).Name
next
importCols = mid(importCols, 2)

DoCmd.RunSQL _
    "INSERT INTO Tbl_ImportDump (Col1, Col2, Col3) " & _
    "SELECT " & importCols & " FROM Import"
```

Comment: John
I tried that out but i came with the same issue. The Tbl_ImportDump currently has no fields and when i try to "insert into" it gives me an error 3127, statement contains the following unknown field. 
I was hoping an "insert into" would add new fields if they are not their.
Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: Short answer is you can't do that - however I'm not sure at this point just exactly what it is you are trying, and thus I cannot answer at this time. Pls add to your post what the current structure of Tbl_ImportDump is, and an example row of data it already contains - assuming it exists (and if it doesn't say so); 2nd, provide an idea of what columns/data exists in the Import table - and leave me a comment here, on my answer to say you've done, so Stack Overflow will notify me.

Comment: John, 

I receive dozens of spreadsheet from different user with what should be similar information; what i mean by that is one user will have a spreadsheet laid out with headers titled as Date|Name|Loss while another user can label headers as Date|First_Name|Recovery. So the headers titles are different but they mean the same thing. 
So  i made a Table made where i have all the possible different naming convention from user and what it should be converted to. 
So i want to import these spreadsheet and convert those headers into a standard name convention.
i hope my explanation helps

Comment: John when i run the code it give me error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set" point to rs.OpenRecordset "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Import"

Comment: so i was thinking if there may be a better way. since i have  Tbl_Standization with columns    UserHeader | StandardHeader. would i just be able to have a sql look during import for header matching "Userheader and than convert it to what it would correlate into Standardheader?

Comment: I don't use DAO recordsets. The syntax might be meant to be SET rs = OpenRecordset("SELECT ...") or something like that.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand